# Error reverse engineering Sql Server database to model using EF Core 1.0.1 in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, scaffolding

I am creating a .Net Core 1.0.1 Web API in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, using EF Core.
I am trying to reverse engineer to a model from a database hosted locally on Sql Server 2016 Express, on my Windows 10 Home 64 bit PC.
I am following this tutorial: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model

The tutorial says I need to run this command in the Package Manager Console to reverse engineer my model:

**Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models**

So, I modified the connection string to connect to my database as follows:

**Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=DESKTOP-AEAOCON\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=propworx;Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models**

and ran it. But I get the following error:

> Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=DESKTOP-AEAOCON\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Ca ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Scaffold-DbContext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The tutorial does mention the following:

> If you receive an error stating the term ‘Scaffold-DbContext’ is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, then close and reopen Visual
>   Studio.

But I've done this and it hasn't helped. Any ideas anyone?

This is my project.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I added these two lines to the project.json file:
    
    
**"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1"**

which is apparently required for the Scaffold-DbContext to work... But now I get this error:


    _Cannot execute this command because_


Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.

Comment: Ok, I read somewhere .Net cannot create model in a Class Library project, so I tried again in a Console application. I now get a different error message:

PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=DESKTOP-AEAOCON\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=propworx;Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Verbose
Using framework 'netcoreapp1.0'
Using data directory 'c:\users\fabs-lenovoy70\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApp1\src\ConsoleApp1\.\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0'
Build started...
Build failed.